# cannot access launcher or onboard when unetbootin asked for password

Tags: launcher, password, synaptic, unetbootin, administrator

when i try to start unetbootin it usually asked for password. But when it asked for password ,i can not access luncher, and the onboard is also not access able during this time. On the other hand, in case of synaptic it ask for password, but i have access to luncher and i can also use onboard. Can any one tell me how to access onboard from luncher icon when unetbootin asked for password. Thank you.

Comment: But you can be able to run the application via terminal, like `sudo unetbootin`.

Comment: yes i can, but is there a way to access onboard even it asked for password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to access onboard while unetbootin asks for password(While you try to open it from as a normal user).IMO it's a bug in unetbootin.So try these two commands on terminal via onboard to run unetbootin.

```
sudo unetbootin
```

It opens the unetbootin application with super user do permissions.

```
/usr/bin/unetbootin 'rootcheck="no"'
```

It won't prompt you to enter `sudo` password, because rootcheck is disabled.

Comment: thank you , and one more thing, i am not sure i should ask it or not , but anyway can you tell me how to search about bug on particular subject.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug to report a bug.[Search in google](https://www.google.com/search?client=browser-ubuntu&hs=SN0&channel=fe&hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+file+a+bug+in+Ubuntu&btnG=#channel=fe&hl=en&q=unetbootin+bug+report) for search for bug about a particular subject.